# Finding and showing element in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any easy way to search through an arraylist?
i see there are many things to do with collections like removeAll() and add() is there anything like this for searching through the list

Comment: And the problem is... ?

Comment: What you want done is to search a list for a specific customer? Just iterate over the list and add a IF statement inside the loop that compares the current customerID with the one you are looking for

Comment: could you filter your code into a sscce (http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your `UserArchive` class that loops through the list and compares each user id to the one passed in.

```
public User findById(int id) {
    for (User u : list) {
        if (u.getCustomerID() == id) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null; // or empty User
}
```

Comment: I might be an idiot, or just tired. Anyways, how can this method be applied to the SalesWindow class?

Comment: @user2248471 You need to add logic to that class that does something when the use clicks the `findCustomer` button.  That's where you'd call this method.

Comment: This is what I got. The problem I get is that I can't convert from User to String. Heres the code I got in SalesWindow. any inputs?     public void findCustomer()
 {
  String firstname = firstNameField.getText();
  
  if(!firstname.equals(""))
  {
   String result = list.findById(firstname);
   outputText.setText(result);
  }
 }

Comment: oh, and i changed to find the customer by name

Comment: @user2248471 LinkedList doesn't have a `findById(String)` method. Did you change the type of `list` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of do a if in your loop and look the id for each instance of User in the loop:

```
for (User user : list) {
    if (user.getCustomerID == [The id to lookup]) {
       // Whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Or you could override the equals() method for your User class and unlock the
List.contains function if you compare another instance of User instead of the CustomerID.

The equals' functions header say:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

This is why you got to override equals for you object. A lot of functions use equals() for object and if you care the result to be good, you have to override the function.

```
// Or whatever instance of User you want to compare
User custToLookup = new User(idToLookup, "", "", "");

// You could stop here if you only want to know if the instance exist in the list
if (list.contains(custToLookup)){
    for (User user : list) {
        if (user.equals(custToLookup) {
            // Whatever you want to do
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit : Forgot some words